# Zip a folder using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, zip, etl

I am trying to zip a Folder in SSIS, there are 12 files in the source folder and I need to zipthat folder. I can get the files to zip fine my problem is the folders.

I have to use winzip to create the zipped packages.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial. I haven't been able to implement any of the samples that I have found.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried and refer the examples you used to avoid unnecessary *"try this .. oh I tried that, it didn't work"* back and forth.

Comment: It can help you start [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378321/how-to-zip-a-folder-using-ssis-2008-without-using-any-third-party-s-w/38481869#38481869)

Comment: Hello @alex Appreciate your help! I tried doing by your way. I did exactly the way u suggested but my package is simply getting executed successfully and not compressing the folder. Consider the situation the way i tried..sFolderCompressed --> F:\Archieve\test.zip ,sFolderSource --> F:\Source\test..these are the value I passed and called them in Read Only variable in Script task as you suggested. But nothing got changed. Please correct me where i made mistake.

Comment: try with sFolderCompressed --> F:\Archieve\test, don't use F:\Archieve\test.zip; I hope this help.

Comment: I done a change ...... no changes happen @alex...

Comment: Are you running the command locally or on a server? Probably your windows version is more up to date and does not allow zip via command line...
We have to look for other solutions...I'm sorry!

Comment: ok.. Thanks @alex

Answer (score 4):

Adding a Script Task, yuo can use the ZipFile (class) [here reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx), you must refer to the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly in the project (.NET Framework 4.5).

You need to provide to the Script Task the folder to be zipped and the name of the compressed folder as ReadOnlyVariables (to be added in the tab ReadOnlyVariables)

These two variables must be defined in the Variables tab (String type) of the package and can be changed dynamically through a cycle (eg. for each)

I use these two variables:

```
sFolderCompressed - the folder '.zip' that you want to obtain eg. C:\folder1\result.zip 
sFolderSource - the source folder containing the files affected eg. C:\folder1\folder2
```

[image]

The script is made using c#, choose Script Language: Microsoft Visual C#

[image]

This is the code to be added in the Main method:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string zipPath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::sFolderCompressed"].Value;
            string startPath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::sFolderSource"].Value;


            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            // Log the exception
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

I hope can help.

Comment: @ɐlǝx . Great. It helped me a lot.

Comment: hello i'm using VS 2010 and i got an error when i try to use your method, i have used the namesace also : Error 1 The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Hi, you have to add the assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem to your project before; Right Click References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework -> check System.IO.Compression.FileSystem  and then OK (you maight see the item in Reference list)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 7zip it is free. Take a look at [7zip command line user guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm)  it contains all commands you need

And use a script task or an execute process task to achieve this. Also there are other useful links:

- https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

**UPDATE 1**

you can follow this link for winzip:

- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?202918-Well-WinZip-Command-Line-Folders-to-Zip-keep-folder-structure-

In the link above they suggested using this command:

```
 wzzip "c:\Test.zip" "c:\myfolder" -exPR
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my user they use winzip only i dont have permission to use 7 zip.. please share a solution with winzip

Answer (score 0):

Write these things in bat file...
"C:\Program Files\WinZip\WINZIP64.EXE" -a "C:\Desktop\destination_folder\Sample.zip"   "C:\Desktop\Sample"

In Execute process task:

Mention the location of bat file in Execute process Task-->Process-->Executable.

It's work fine.