# Unzip .tar.gz files in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, tar, unzip, gzip

I have a `.tar.gz` file. Now i need to unpack these files with SSIS package. Previously did unzip and delete for `.zip` files with the help of For each container and script task. Not sure how to do it for `.tar.gz` files. Any help?

Comment: `.tar.gz` can be unzipped using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), it is a free application, i faced the same situation before, and it works perfectly using `Execute process task`. Check the links in my answer for command line examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an execute process task to achieve this *(or using process from Script task)*, but you have to install a ZIP application like `7Zip` or `Winzip` or else. And use command line to Zip or Unzip archives.

Follow one of these links for more details:

- [Zip a folder using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416229/zip-a-folder-using-ssis/44418705#44418705)
- [7Zip command line examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)
- [What command line parameters does WinZip support?](http://www.memecode.com/docs/winzip.html)